# How to add slick-active class in Slider dots in React Slick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I used react-slick and made a carousel using Slider component. The code is bellow,

```
const carousel = (props) => {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: '50%', marginTop: '20px' }}>
            <Slider {...settings}>
                <div className={text__bar}>
                    <div >
                        <font>Lorum Ipsum 1</font>
                    </div>
                    <div className={slide1} />
                </div>
                <div className={text__bar}>
                    <div>
                        <font>Lorum Ipsum 2</font>
                    </div>
                    <div className={slide1} />
                </div>
                <div className={text__bar}>
                    <div>
                        <font>Lorum Ipsum 3</font>
                    </div>
                    <div className={slide1} />
                </div>
            </Slider>
            <div className={purple__bar}></div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And the settings object,

```
const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    className: SlickMain,
    dotsClass: button__bar,
    arrows: false,
};
```

I have added some extra CSS to style my carousel dots (buttons) to look like bellow,

[image: dotbar]

When examined by the developer tools the button related to the currently shown slide gets a CSS class injected named 'slick-active'

[image: injected-class]

What I need to do is change the background color of the button corresponding to the slide, to black relapsing the current color purple.

What I did was,

```
.button__bar li.slick-active button {
    opacity: .75;
    color: #000
}
```

But it won't work. What am I missing?

**.button__bar** is the dotsClass I have given to dots in settings object.

Comment: Do you need to style `.button__bar li.slick-active` instead of `.button__bar li.slick-active button`? Unless the button actually exists inside `li`.

Comment: `button` is inside `li`

Comment: Looking at examples the button style is applied using `:before` pseudo class, have you tried that? `.button__bar li.slick-active button:before { opacity: .75;
    color: #000
}`

Comment: Yes and there's no need to apply `before`.

Comment: Do you want to use `dotsClass: 'button__bar'` instead of using `button__bar` object here?

Comment: @HankChiu I'm using css modules. So I import the classes from .css file and destructure the objects in the import statement. That's why I'm using button__bar

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is happening because I'm using CSS-Modules to load my CSS file. In the following code example, you can clearly see what's happening.

https://codesandbox.io/s/1z2lnox5rq?fontsize=14

So as a solution what I did was adding bellow methods to settings object.

```
const settings = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 1000,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  className: slickMain,
  dotsClass: button__bar,
  arrows: false,
  beforeChange: (prev, next) => {
    this.setState({ currentSlide: next });
  },
  // afterChange: (index) => this.setState({ currentSlide: index }),
  appendDots: dots => {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {dots.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>{item.props.children}</li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  },
  customPaging: index => {
    return (
      <button style={index === this.state.currentSlide ? testSettings : null}>
        {index + 1}
      </button>
    )
  }
};
```

To solve my problem, I used `beforeChange` to acquire the next slide index and saved it in the state. Then using `appendDots` a `div` with a `ul`, `li` is injected to the dot-bar section which. Inside the `li`, a `button` passed as a child prop using `customPaging` method. When the current slide equals the  index of the `customPaging`, which is in the state, then a class is injected with a background color.

```
const testSettings = {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    outline: '0'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is using material ui here is how it could work

```
const settings: Settings = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dotsClass: `slick-dots ${classes.dots}`,
};
// your classes created with material ui
makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
// may not be the best way but it works
  dots: {
    bottom: 0,
    "& li.slick-active button::before": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
    "& li": {
      "& button::before": {
      fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(14),
      color: "#fff",
      opacity: 0.5,
    },
  }
}))
```

Here is a codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-snow-h9rwq?file=/src/App.tsx

Please note, that I haven't checked it with importing slick css i.e.

```
// Import css files
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

but used cdn instead

Answer (score 2):

I have made this work just with CSS Modules with the use of `:global()`

in your specific case adding `li.slick-active` --> `:global(li.slick-active)`

```
.button__bar :global(li.slick-active) button {
  opacity: .75;
  color: #000
}
```

Here a [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-css-modules-2jb57) forked from yours